# Full page scroll

Tags: jquery, css, matrix, transform

### Full page (vertical) slider

I would like to create a full page slider (up and down).
What I mean is that you can use the mousewheel to scroll, but instead of scrolling, the entire page slides to the next page div: .

Reason I ask: I would love to learn more about matrix and optimizing animations/transition.

» » [Awesome example](http://robin-noguier.com/) « «

Comment: Here you go: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ an example of div scrolling of an entire page

Comment: @Rotan075 that's a plugin m8. Lots of  unnecessary things

Comment: Often those plugins are making your life easier instead of writing it on your own. If you want to write it yourself start trying and if you get stuck try asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

So... 22 hours later and I learned a lot thanks to some critical opinions and tips from you guys.

Some stackoverflow helpers, thanks again:

- [J.T. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)
- [Rotan075](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976975/rotan075)

**Anyways.. Here's my code:**

```js
// jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
    // --- VARIABLES
    var fullAnimation = false;
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var lastSlide = $('.page').length - 1;
    var scrollDirection = "";

    // --- FUNCTIONS
    function slidePage(scrollDirection, currentSlide) {
        fullAnimation = false;
        if(scrollDirection == "down") {
            $('.current-slide-animating').toggleClass('current-slide-animating prev-slide');
            $('.page').eq(currentSlide - 1).addClass('prev-slide');
            if(currentSlide != lastSlide) {
                $('.page').eq(currentSlide + 1).addClass('next-slide');
            }
        } else {
            $('.current-slide-animating').toggleClass('current-slide-animating next-slide');
            $('.page').eq(currentSlide + 1).addClass('next-slide');
            if(currentSlide != 0) {
                $('.page').eq(currentSlide - 1).addClass('prev-slide');
            }
        } 
    }

    // --- EVENTS
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
        scrollDirection = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? "up" : "down";
        if(fullAnimation == false) {
            // if scroll down
            if(currentSlide != lastSlide && scrollDirection == "down") {
                fullAnimation = true;
                currentSlide += 1;
                $('.current-slide').toggleClass('current-slide current-slide-animating')
                $('.next-slide').toggleClass('next-slide current-slide');
                $('.page.prev-slide').removeClass('prev-slide');
                $('.page.next-slide').removeClass('next-slide');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    slidePage(scrollDirection, currentSlide)
                }, 600);
            }
            // if scroll up
            if(currentSlide != 0 && scrollDirection == "up") {
                fullAnimation = true;
                currentSlide -= 1;
                $('.current-slide').toggleClass('current-slide current-slide-animating')
                $('.prev-slide').toggleClass('prev-slide current-slide');
                $('.page.prev-slide').removeClass('prev-slide');
                $('.page.next-slide').removeClass('next-slide');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    slidePage(scrollDirection, currentSlide)
                }, 600);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300italic,300,400,400italic,500);

*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

html {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #333;
    fill: currentColor;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 16.666667em;
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1.65em;
}

main {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.main, .page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.page {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.page.current-slide {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition:
        opacity 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),
        -webkit-transform 600ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),
        transform 600ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}
.page.current-slide-animating {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
    transform: scale(.9);
    transition:
        opacity 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1) 100ms,
        -webkit-transform 500ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),
        transform 500ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}
.page.prev-slide,
.page.next-slide {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
.page.prev-slide {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.page.next-slide {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.page.one {
    background-color: #4bffc5;
}
.page.two {
    background-color: #a497ff;
}
.page.three {
    background-color: #ff5152;
}
.page.four {
    background-color: #3d98ff;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <!-- get a main div -->
        <div class="main">
            <!-- this is the div where you will place your desktop website -->
            <div class="page one current-slide"></div>
            <div class="page two next-slide"></div>
            <div class="page three"></div>
            <div class="page four"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Click full page for better view